# How to deal with integrals with cubed differentials, for example, $\int(f(x)f(y)f(x,y)d^3xd^3y)$

Tags: integration

I am tasked with solving a longer problem, one part of which involves evaluating an integral that looks a bit like this:
$$\int(f(x)f(y)f(x,y)d^3xd^3y)$$

I do not know how to address the differentials as they have this cubed exponent. I feel like it is something obvious but I find myself stumped.

Comment: This is physicists’ notation for integrating over $3$-space. They are not “cubed differentials.”

Comment: You cannot have in the same formula $f(x)$ and $f(x,y)$.